# Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Cannot handle conversion to jumbo index

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, build-error, dex

I have an issue when compiling an Android project in Eclipse. I added 3 external jars that I needed, and now I get this issue:

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Cannot handle conversion to jumbo index!
```

The only resource I have come across that has any solution is [this one](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/adt-dev/tuLXN9GkVas). Unfortunately, adding the referenced line to project.properties and cleaning as the resource recommended didn't work. If anyone else has faced this problem before, could you let me know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue 
Increase heap size of eclipse.ini 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms512m
-Xmx2g

is my current settings